# If $\ $ $yx_n\to 0 $ for all $y$ in a C$^*$-algebra, Is it true that $x_n$ is weakly convergent to $0$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, hilbert-spaces

> $A$ is a C$^*\! $-algebra and $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq A $.
>    If $\ $ $yx_n\to 0 $  for all  $y\in A$, Is it true that $x_n$ is weakly
>   convergent to $0$  ?

For unitals this is trivial. For  characters like 
$w\in \Omega (A)$ we have $w(x_n)\to 0$ but if for all functionals, I don't know.

Comment: By the Cohen--Hewitt factorization $A\times A^*\ni(a,\phi)\mapsto \phi(\,\cdot\,a)\in A^*$ is surjective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's true. By the GNS construction, every bounded linear functional on $A$ is of the form $A\ni a\mapsto \langle \pi(a)\xi,\eta \rangle$ for some non-degenerate *-representation $\pi$ on $H$ and $\xi,\eta\in H$. By the Cohen--Hewitt factorization theorem, $H=\pi(A)H$ (no need to take the closure). Consequently, $A\times A^*\ni (a,\phi)\mapsto \phi(a,\,\cdot\,)\in A^*$ is surjective.